# The name of a German Nazi supporter who owned many newspapers

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, propaganda

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the name of the Nazi supporter was that owned 53 German newspapers and dedicated all of them to Hitler to use to spread his Nazi message through one of the campaigns?  I think he was Alfred somebody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you probably mean [Alfred Hugenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Hugenberg)